# FF: error "You've launched an older version of firefox" - And changes that really impact on profile format

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

When opening my profile with a different FF browser, I've received the error "You've launched an older version of firefox" and it offer me 2 option "Exit" and " Create new Profile"

[image: You've launched an older version of firefox]

I understand that format for data stores on profile can change with the time being but in my case the last Firefox was v114 and the older v112.

I don't think that Firefox has introduced big changes impacting on profile but that this is an automatic rule+popup message, so.

- How can i force the load of "a non compliance" profile?
- How can i know about changes that really impacting on the profile data?

Notes:

BTW time ago firefox was not that picky when loading a profile folder with a different and older browsers and I never had problems.

And theoretically I should have both binary folders with v112, but one firefox installation got unexpectedly updated.

Answer (score 3):

Before doing the following advice, make a backup of the existing
Firefox user profile folders, found by going to `about:profiles` in your browser. The profile folder is usually located in
`%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`.

Now run the command `firefox -allow-downgrade`.
Firefox should launch, load your existing profiles and work as usual.

The next time after this, run Firefox as usual without this
additional parameter.

This is not recommended if there is too great a distance between
the two versions, but for versions 114 and 112 it should work.

Comment: good reminder about the backup. It is a key step. I am still thing that Mozilla should keep a register with changes impacting on the profile and a 3rd button "Yes, I accept the risk", because using an older firefox sometimes is not optional.

Comment: In your answer you have an en dash unicode character instead of an ascii hyphen. I'm on macos and it was just ignoring the command until I realized. I've submitted an edit to the answer, needs to be approved. So, on macos:

Go to `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS` in Terminal and run `./firefox -allow-downgrade`

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: I don't see the dash, but just in case I have re-typed all the dashes in the answer. Hope it's OK now.

Comment: @harrymc I verified using `od`, and you can see even the edit shows the dash is different. You can check online as well here https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%80%93-, and copy paste in your before/after. I'm not sure why you wanted to reject my edit, since I included a system agnostic, but I'm glad it's fixed now.

Comment: @harrymc I love your microsoft style stubbornness, the edited history is truly glorious. May you make SO proud!

Answer (score -1):

I recently experienced the same error after Firefox got downgraded (probably by the software management tool of my company which wasn't updated yet and overwrote my Firefox installation).

If anyone experiences a similar scenario (and wants to save their set-up): check which Firefox version you currently have installed and try to download a later version. Install it and hopefully your set-up/configuration is saved.

Answer (score -1):

I manually changed the profiles this way:

1/ create a new profile

2/ Go to the profile folder

3/ look up two values in those files:

- profiles/blablabla.default/compatibility.ini

`LastVersion=????`

- profiles/blablabla.default/prefs.js:

`user_pref("browser.migration.version", ???);`

4/ copy those values into the respective original files

PS: prefs.js is perhaps not necessary, but compatibility.ini is mandatory.

**Caution:** this system is made by firefox for good reasons. It might break your profile. At least a good backup seem necessary :-)